# Download entire website with wget and ignore 404

Tags: wget

I want to download an entire website where the webserver responds with a 404 status code on all pages but sends content anyways. The website is working in every browser just fine, even though it's CMS is totally broken.
Background is to download all images from the site as the CMS Admin Panel and the server are inaccessible due to severely broken infrastructure. Goal is to make the page entirely new.

The command line is as following:

```
wget \
  --recursive \
  --page-requisites \
  --html-extension \
  --convert-links \
  --content-on-error \
  --restrict-file-names=windows \
  --domains rainers-modellbau.at \
  --no-parent \
  www.rainers-modellbau.at
```

My issue is that the --content-on-error parameter is not working and I just get a "ERROR 404: Not Found." error message.

Using Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Which version of `wget` are you using i.e. what is output when you do `wget --version`?

Comment: GNU Wget 1.20.3